# My interface when triggered get NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, interface, nullpointerexception

I try a Toast Message interface. If app not connection internet, I want show a Toast Message and I'm wanting java interfaces.

This is `MotherActivity.java`. This file implement `ToastMessagges.ToastMessaggeCallback`

```
   public class MotherActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ToastMessagges.ToastMessaggeCallback {

        ToastMessagges toastMessagges;

        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_mother);

            toastMessagges      = new ToastMessagges();

            AppStarter();
        }

        private void AppStarter(){

            boolean checkinternet   = InternetControl.checkInternetConnection( getApplicationContext() );
            if( checkinternet ) {
                toastMessagges.show_toast_messagge();
            }
            else {

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void LongToastMessagge() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}
}
```

This is my ToastMessagges.java file.

```
public class ToastMessagges {

    ToastMessaggeCallback toastMessaggeCallback;
    public void show_toast_messagge(){
        toastMessaggeCallback.LongToastMessagge();
    }


    public static interface ToastMessaggeCallback {
        public void LongToastMessagge();
    }
}
```

When the start this app. I get NullPointerException error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.medyasef.bulenttirasnewapp.bulenttiras.functions.ToastMessagges.show_toast_messagge(ToastMessagges.java:22)
            at com.medyasef.bulenttirasnewapp.bulenttiras.MotherActivity.AppStarter(MotherActivity.java:36)
            at com.medyasef.bulenttirasnewapp.bulenttiras.MotherActivity.onCreate(MotherActivity.java:29)
```

ToastMessagges.java:22

```
toastMessaggeCallback.LongToastMessagge();
```

Sorry bad english.
Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you initialize `ToastMessaggeCallback toastMessaggeCallback`?

Comment: I guess not. How to initialize ToastMessaggeCallback toastMessaggeCallback ?

Answer (score 3):

You haven't initialized you `ToastMessaggeCallback toastMessaggeCallback`.

To do this, write

```
ToastMessaggeCallback toastMessaggeCallback = new ToastMessaggeCallback(){

    public void LongToastMessagge(){
        // add some toasting code here
    }

};
```

This will make an object implementing your interface (called "anonymous class"). Of course, your `ToastMessaggeCallback` should do something in the method `LongToastMessagge`, so add the desired code there.

Comment: First thanx exception1. My english little weak. So I cant not tell exactly. Your sample is working but do not need to implement. I want override ToastMessaggeCallback and this interface must work in MotherActivity. Like this 

@Override
    public void LongToastMessagge() {
        Log.d("denemeolkun","Like This Video");
    }

I must you can understand me. I wanting learn interfaces. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend you to create a `Util` class instead of `Interface`. I'm here giving you an example of `Util` class.

```
public class Util {

    public static void showToast(Context context, String text) {

        Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

Then call the `showToast()` method from your activity as follows...

```
Util.showToast(YourActivity.this, "text");
```

**Update:**

Declare your `Interface` as a individual, not inside a class  as below...

```
public interface ToastMessaggeCallback {

    public void showLongToastMessagge(String text);

}
```

Then implement the `Interface` as follows...

```
public class MotherActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ToastMessaggeCallback {

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mother);

        AppStarter();
    }

    private void AppStarter(){

        boolean checkinternet   = InternetControl.checkInternetConnection( getApplicationContext() );
        if( checkinternet ) {

            showLongToastMessagge("Hello World");

        }
        else {

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void showLongToastMessagge(String text) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }
}
```

Comment: First thanks your help. But I want at the same time Java interface. My problem only little a problem.

Comment: Thanx again @HamidShatu. This sample is working clean for me.But That's not exactly what I want. I'm trying to figure out the interface structure. My english little weak. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `ToastMessagges` class needs to provide a method to register the callback.  Then, your `Activity` needs to call this method to register itself as the callback, right after you construct the `ToastMessages` object.